# Xamarin Forms Connect to Wifi >= API Level 29

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-wifi

I try to connect to a specific Wifi but everytime I get a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
(commented in code)

Here is my method

```
public static Task ConnectToWifi(Wifi wifi)
        {
            var wifiSpecififier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .SetSsid(wifi.SSID)
                .SetWpa2Passphrase(wifi.Password)
                .SetIsHiddenSsid(wifi.Hidden)
                .Build();

            var request = new Android.Net.NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .AddTransportType(Android.Net.TransportType.Wifi)
                .RemoveCapability(Android.Net.NetCapability.Internet)
                .SetNetworkSpecifier(wifiSpecififier)
                .Build();

            var connectivityManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(
                Android.App.Application.ConnectivityService) as Android.Net.ConnectivityManager;

            connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, new NetworkCallback()); //nullex

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Here is my NetworkCallback class

```
public class NetworkCallback : Android.Net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    {
        public static Android.Content.Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        Android.Net.ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (Android.Net.ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Android.App.Application.ConnectivityService);

        public override void OnAvailable(Android.Net.Network network)
        {
            base.OnAvailable(network);
            connectivityManager.BindProcessToNetwork(network);
        }

        public override void OnUnavailable() => base.OnUnavailable();
    }
```

Edit:

at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception (System.Exception e) [0x0000e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x0001d] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:111
at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Comment: if you know which line causes the exception, then you need to determine which element on that line is null.  We can't do that for you.  Use the debugger or examine the stack trace for more info

Comment: Good question lol i debug this an nothing is null

Comment: Obviously something is.  Look at the stack trace to see what the root cause is

Comment: request = {NetworkRequest [ NONE id=0, [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN Specifier: <WifiNetworkSpecifier [, SSID Match pattern=PatternMatcher{LITERAL: Fu5704Wolke}, BSSID Match pattern=Pair{00:00:00:00:00:00 00:00:00:00:00:00}, SSID="Fu5704Wolke", BSSID=null]> Uid: 10154 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: -1 RequestorPackageName: null] ]} AND new NetworkCallback() = {crc64c1fb061c2ccb06a5.NetworkCallback@1671fdb}

Comment: My stacktrace:  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception (System.Exception e) [0x0000e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12 
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x0001d] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:111 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Comment: The exception source is Mono.Android

Comment: You can try to change the `connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, new NetworkCallback())` to`connectivityManager.RegisterNetworkCallback(request, new NetworkCallback())`.

Comment: I get the Same exception when I try this :(

Comment: You can create a instance of the NetworkCallback() to check the problem is it or not such as `var callback = new NetworkCallback();    connectivityManager.RegisterNetworkCallback(request, callback))`

Comment: i tried this and connectivitymanager.RequestNetwork() or connectivymanager.RegisterNetworkCallback() throws this exact same exception i guess there is something wrong with mono android or something.

Comment: What I mean is that there may be something null in your code, so you can try to use `var callback = new NetworkCallback();   ` to check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add any required permissions, I think you need this to your AppManifest to fix the error:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```